# Windows Phone Universal App MediaCapture alternatives

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I have a big problem with Universal App's *MediaCapture*. In [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c559c874-9663-476d-8eed-72995a8680db/are-there-known-problems-with-81-mediacapture-initializeasync?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK) link I found that the problem might be the update installed on the phone which goes in conflict with this class.

I tryed some phones and all phones with *Windows phone 8.1 Update* crushes on *MediaCapture* initializing. No errors, just the phone quits the app.

In this article they said that it is due to a bug which closes the camera stopping the application.

Now, my problem is to find an alternative to *MediaCapture*, because half phones I need are with update 1 and half with update2 and I can't develop the app only for half customers.

Does any of you knows an alternative class?

PS: phones where app crushes have this update: ***8.10.14219.341***

Thanks all and sorry for my not perfect english.

Comment: I was also facing issues and I also thought it was due to update but it might be because Camera is not available and needs to be free from any other object or class or app using it. You should make a case for checking this and then try again. It was same case for me

Comment: @Rohit how should I free it? but are you sure about it? it was the same even restarting my phone and using this app as first :(

Comment: If your phone freezes when Initializing MediaCapture in your app and runs properly in Camera app or any other app then it can be case of freeing up the MediaCapture. I'm posting my code sample for this. Try this if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using [CameraCaptureTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead? It can be as simple as this:

```
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;
cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);

cameraCaptureTask.Show();
```

And then this is what you can do when the user is done capturing:

```
void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.        
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This class is not for Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Right! Edited the answer to recommend CameraCaptureTask instead. I forget not everyone is doing Win10 UWP yet, sorry!

Comment: Hi, sorry but i was on holiday and I will be back to this project on Wednesday. I will try this as soon as possible, thanks a lot for the reply! I will coment here once done :)

Comment: I don't know why but in my solution I can't include Microsoft.Phone namespace, so no CameraCapture is avaiable..

Comment: They may only be available for Silverlight projects. I would recommend you instead target Windows 10 devices (UWP) and use CameraCaptureUI instead.

Comment: I can't unfortunatly, I will try finding something thanks anyway!